# Programmatically Setting reportviewer local report path in a windows forms application

Tags: winforms, clickonce, reportviewer, rdlc, reportingservices-2005

I have a windows forms application that uses the reportViewer control to display a few reports.

```
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"Reports\report.rdlc");
```

The code above works if i create a setup file that installs the application on any client machine but fails when i deploy the application on the company intranet using ClickOnce Deployment.

I have the .rdlc Build Action set to Content and Copy To OutPut Directory set to Copy Always.

**Below is the code**

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("myReportDataSourceHere", authorisedLeave);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"rdlcReports\myReportName.rdlc");

reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I then get the error message below when trying to install the application from the ClickOnce installation link in the browser.

> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   C:\Users\myWindowsUserName\Desktop\ProjectName.appref-ms| resulted in
>   exception.

Following failure messages were detected:

Downloading `http://Server1`/My Project Name/Application
Files/MyProjectName_1_0_0_25/rdlcReports/myReportName.rdlc did not
succeed.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: How are you including your myReportName.rdlc with the ClickOnce install?  How are you creating the folder where it is should reside?